# Schema that changes based on attribute values

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

I want to be able to change the expected child elements of a parent element when the parent element has a particular attribute value set.

So the following would validate:

```
<Parent childConfig="A">
    <Child validForConfigA="ABC"/>
</Parent>
```

or:

```
<Parent childConfig="B">
    <Child validForConfigB="XYZ"/>
</Parent>
```

But this snippet would not validate (because the attribute "validForConfigB" is not valid when the parent's childConfig="A"):

```
<Parent childConfig="A">
    <Child validForConfigB="ABC"/>
</Parent>
```

Can this kind of logic work in DTD or XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a DTD, but with an XML Schema 1.1 validator you should be able to  use [*type alternatives*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative).